# Встроенный установщик программ VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, install

Для старых версий есть руководства, как создать инсталлятор. К решению добавляется проект Setup Wizard. В VS 2019 такого типа проекта нет.
Как в VS 2019 можно создать установщик программы?

Answer (score 0):

Через установку расширений ставится. Меню "Расширение" и т.д.